# flatpickr (angular 4.0) is not displaying the selected date on page load

Tags: angularjs

An angular 4.0 wrapper for flatpickr does not show the selected date:

```html
<input
    class="form-control"
    name="startDate"
    type="text"
    mwlFlatpickr
    [(ngModel)]="event.start"
    (ngModelChange)="refresh.next()"
    [altInput]="true"
    [convertModelValue]="true"
    [enableTime]="true" dateFormat="Y-m-dTH:i"
    [minDate]="getMinDate(event.start)"
    [maxDate]="event.end"
    altFormat="Y-m-d'
    placeholder="Not set"
/>
```

Comment: what version of `flatpickr` are you using?

Comment: angularx-flatpickr -1.0.0